# Taking pointer from integer without a cast. Know what but don't know how

Tags: c++, c++14

Thanks for reading this ask. Idk how i can fixed my error.
I know why i have it's errors, but i dont know how i can fix it. 
Look. This is my class ConsoleDisplay

```
class ConsoleDisplay {
public:
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >::iterator screenIt_t;
typedef std::vector<std::string>::iterator panelIt_t;

// Constructor
ConsoleDisplay(const char w[], const char panels, const char height);

void clear();
void refresh();
void write(const std::string& str);
void write(const unsigned char panel, const std::string& str);
void write(const unsigned char panel, const unsigned char row, const 
std::string& str);
private:
const std::vector<char> w;
const char h, p;
char lastRow;
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > screen;
std::vector<std::string> stream;
};
```

And this is my one of main.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
ConsoleDisplay display(3, 30, 40);
BS_Board board(cin, cout);

display.clear();
board.writeShipGrid(display);
board.writeAttackGrid(display);
display.refresh();

return 0;
}
```

I really do not know how to fix this problem. I hope for you, many thanks for your attention.

Comment: UPD : Sorry i was I forgot to add the error place. ConsoleDisplay display(3,30,40) :error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Okay, please explain what you expect to achieve by passing `3` where a `const char w[]` is expected.

Comment: This method is designed for the game "Battleship." And i think i just idiot and just now i fixed it..

Comment: Glad it worked out. Feel free to answer your own question with how you fixed it, or remove the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
ConsoleDisplay(const char w[], const char panels, const char height);
```

Requires three parameters to construct.  They need to be char array, panels and height.

```
ConsoleDisplay display( "name", 3,  40 );
```

Comment: I see three arguments, not four... there is no `width`.